# Fragment without activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been asked an interview question: **Can a fragment exist without activity**? I searched for answers but didn't get a proper answer and explanation. Can someone help?

Comment: read the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html.

Comment: Quoting docs "A fragment is not required to be a part of the activity layout; you may also use a fragment without its own UI as an invisible worker for the activity". Only in this case you can have fragment not attached to activity

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can do this anywhere:

```
new YourFragment();
```

As fragments must have a parameter-less constructor.

However its [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) doesn't kick in until it is attached. So `onAttach`, `onCreate`, `onCreateView`, etc. are only called when it is attached. So most fragments do nothing until they are attached.

Comment: Somebody asked me if a service can have Fragment. I said yes, he was surprised. But one should remember that one can have Fragment and call any of its method but as mentioned by @weston its life-cycle will not kick in until attached to Activity. Also, one need instance of FragmentManager to do manage them (which is possible only in Activity).

Comment: Please share a proper example link.

Answer (score 14):

It can exist as an object in memory (by creating it with `new`), but it needs to be attached to an Activity in order to appear on the screen, assuming it has any UI (fragments don't have to have UI).

Answer (score 6):

A Fragment can exist independently, but in order to display it, you need the help of an Activity. The Activity will act like a container for the Fragment(s).

Answer (score 3):

A `fragment` is not required to be a part of the `Activity layout`; you may also use a `fragment` without its own `UI` as an invisible worker for the `Activity` but it needs to be attached to an `Activity` in order to appear on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you create an instance of the Fragment class, it exists, but in order for it to appear on the UI, you must attach that fragment to an activity because a fragment's lifecycle runs parallel to an activity's lifecycle. Without any call to Activity's onCreate(), there will be no call for onAttach(), onCreate(), onCreateView() and onActivityCreated() of fragment and so it can't be started.

Answer (score 2):

Android app must have an Activity or FragmentActivity that handles the fragment.

Fragment can't be initiated without Activity or FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 2):

I read above top rated answer , i am not disagreeing but android already provides to make independent fragment without activity DialogFragment , which extends fragment . if you want show in full screen first extends DialogFragment then

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);

}
```